# MySQL LIKE and NOT LIKE is missing a record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named **platform** with a column named **entityid**.  The data in entityid is supposed to adhere to the format n.n.n (where n = a number of 1 or more numerals, the first number is a site ID).

If i run this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM platform
```

I get: 16063
So I've got 16063 rows in my table.  When I try to filter for only site 18 I run this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM platform
where entityid like '18.%.%'
```

I get: 4454
So far, so good.  But if I try to find platforms not at site 18:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM platform
where entityid not like '18.%.%'
```

I get: 11608
Here's the problem: 4454 + 11608 = 16062
I'm missing a record.  I think I'm getting all the platforms that are at site 18, and then all the platforms that are not at site 18 - how am I missing one record?

Comment: NULL value?  Find it with `SELECT * FROM platform WHERE entityID NOT IN (SELECT entityID FROM platform WHERE entityID NOT LIKE '18.%.%') AND entityID NOT IN (SELECT entityID FROM platform WHERE entityID LIKE '18.%.%')`

Comment: Most likely you have a record with a null entityid, that will fail all conditions except `is null`.

Comment: Can entityid be null?

Comment: A NULL will fail both conditions.  Check for entityid IS NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably a null value.  Try this and see if it returns a record:

```
select *
from platform
where entityid is null;
```

NULL values fail almost all comparisons (except for `is null`).

Comment: Yep, one record with a NULL entityid.  Thanks!